# Sum of Gaussians into fast Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

here is my problem:

I have two sets of 3d points. Lets call them "Gausspoints" and "XYZ". I define a function which is a sum of Gaussians in which every Gaussian is centered at one of the Gausspoints. Now I want to evaluate this function on the XYZ points: My approach is working fine but it is rather slow. Any idea how to speed it up by exploiting numpy a little better?

```
  def sumgaus(r):
    t=r-Gausspoints
    t=map(np.linalg.norm,t)
    t = -np.power(t,2.0)
    t=np.exp(t)
    res=np.sum(t)
    return res

result=map(sumgaus,XYZ)
```

Thanks for any help

Edit: 
shape of XYZ N*3 and Gausspoints are M*3  with M, N being different integers

Edit2:   I want to apply the following function  on each item in XYZ

[image]

Comment: What are the shapes of those arrays?

Comment: `Gausspoints` is that a global variable, what is the shape ? what is `r` ? why define your problem this way ? what you want is: evalutate sum of gaussians with given mean and variance for each component and each component centered in one of points in XYZ, and your means are what you are calling `Gausspoints`, is that right ?

Comment: Update in the main post

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part is how to vectorize the computation of all the differences between your points without any explicit Python looping or mapping. You can roll out your own implementation using broadcasting by doing something like:

```
dist2 = XYZ[:, np.newaxis, :] - Gausspoints
dist2 *= dist
dist2 = np.sum(dist, axis=-1)
```

And if `XYZ` has shape `(n, 3)` and `Gausspoints` has shape `(m, 3)`, then `dist` will have shape `(n, m)`, with `dist[i, j]` being the distance between points `XYZ[i]` and `Gausspoints[j]`.

It may be easier to understand using [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

dist2 = cdist(XYZ, Gausspoints)
dist2 *= dist2
```

But once you have your array of squared distances, it's child's play:

```
f = np.sum(np.exp(-dist2), axis=1)
```