# Numpy: Generating a 2D Sum of Gaussians pdf as an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, gaussian

I'm trying to generate a [600 x 600] numpy array that contains the sum of 10 Gaussian-like arrays (each with a randomly-generated center).

I've tried using a Gaussian filter to generate the individual Gaussian-like arrays, then summing them up, but I'm sure there's a vectorized way to approach this. Even with `num_centers=10` it's slow, and I might need to sum as many as 20 Gaussians.

There is a similar question here, but it doesn't seem to have a good or conclusive answer and I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem.
[Sum of Gaussians into fast Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121853/sum-of-gaussians-into-fast-numpy)

Here's what I have tried.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


num_centers = 10               # number of Gaussians to sum
sigma = 100                    # std. dev. of each Gaussian
result = np.zeros((600, 600))


for _ in range(num_centers):

    # Pick a random coordinate within the array as the center
    center = np.random.uniform(result.shape).astype(int)

    # Make array with 1 at the center and 0 everywhere else
    temp = np.zeros_like(result)
    temp[center[0], center[1]] = 1

    # Apply filter
    gaussian = gaussian_filter(temp, sigma)

    # Add to result
    result += gaussian


# Result should look like a contour map with several hills
plt.imshow(result * 1000)        # scale up to see the coloring
plt.show()
```

Comment: If your array size is going to be as small, you can just make a 3D array and then sum it in one direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate the loop, and instead create an array with the value 1 at each center and then apply `gaussian_filter` *once* to this array.  All the steps can be vectorized.

Here's an example.  I made `sigma` smaller so it was easier to distinguish the centers, and I increased the width to 800 (for no particular reason :).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


num_centers = 10
sigma = 25
size = (600, 800)

impulses = np.zeros(size)

# rows and cols are the row and column indices of the centers
# of the gaussian peaks.
np.random.seed(123456)
rows, cols = np.unravel_index(np.random.choice(impulses.size, replace=False,
                                               size=num_centers),
                              impulses.shape)
impulses[rows, cols] = 1
# or use this if you want duplicates to sum:
# np.add.at(impulses, (rows, cols), 1)

# Filter impulses to create the result.
result = gaussian_filter(impulses, sigma, mode='nearest')

plt.imshow(result)
plt.show()
```

Here's the plot:

[image: plot]

You can experiment with the `mode` argument of `gaussian_filter` to see which mode works best for you.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! What would be a good approach if I wanted each of the centers to have a different randomly selected sigma?

Comment: This approach wouldn't work if sigma is different for different centers.  It's probably possible to come up with *something* that is fully vectorized, but not here in the comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how you can handle the creation of the random gaussian arrays in a parrallel fashion, as that is what is taking the most time in your code. (I used `timeit` to determine this). This is to be expected, as `gaussian_filter` is a computationally intensive function.

However, I did see a *slight* performance boost by using `np.sum()` on an array of gaussians. This is because calling `np.sum()` once is more efficient than calling `+=` from within a loop.

#### Example

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


num_centers = 10               # number of Gaussians to sum
sigma = 100                    # std. dev. of each Gaussian
holder = np.zeros((num_centers, 600, 600))


for _ in range(num_centers):

    # Pick a random coordinate within the array as the center
    center = np.random.uniform(result.shape).astype(int)

    # Make array with 1 at the center and 0 everywhere else
    temp = np.zeros((600, 600))
    temp[center[0], center[1]] = 1

    # Apply filter
    holder[_] = gaussian_filter(temp, sigma)

result = np.sum(holder, axis=0)

# Result should look like a contour map with several hills
plt.imshow(result * 1000)        # scale up to see the coloring
plt.show()
```