# Efficient sum of Gaussians in 3D with NumPy using large arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gaussian

I have an M x 3 array of 3D coordinates, *coords* (M ~1000-10000), and I would like to compute the sum of Gaussians centered at these coordinates over a mesh grid 3D array. The mesh grid 3D array is typically something like 64 x 64 x 64, but sometimes upwards of 256 x 256 x 256, and can go even larger. I’ve followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121853) to get started, by converting my meshgrid array into an array of N x 3 coordinates, *xyz*, where N is 64^3 or 256^3, etc. However, for large array sizes it takes too much memory to vectorize the entire calculation (understandable since it could approach 1e11 elements and consume a terabyte of RAM) so I’ve broken it up into a loop over M coordinates. However, this is too slow.

I’m wondering if there is any way to speed this up at all without overloading memory. By converting the meshgrid to xyz, I feel like I’ve lost any advantage of the grid being equally spaced, and that somehow, maybe with scipy.ndimage, I should be able to take advantage of the even spacing to speed things up.

Here’s my initial start:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

#create meshgrid
side = 100.
n = 64 #could be 256 or larger
x_ = np.linspace(-side/2,side/2,n)
x,y,z = np.meshgrid(x_,x_,x_,indexing='ij')

#convert meshgrid to list of coordinates
xyz = np.column_stack((x.ravel(),y.ravel(),z.ravel()))

#create some coordinates
coords = np.random.random(size=(1000,3))*side - side/2

def sumofgauss(coords,xyz,sigma):
    """Simple isotropic gaussian sum at coordinate locations."""
    n = int(round(xyz.shape[0]**(1/3.))) #get n samples for reshaping to 3D later
    #this version overloads memory
    #dist = spatial.distance.cdist(coords, xyz)
    #dist *= dist
    #values = 1./np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2) * np.exp(-dist/(2*sigma**2))
    #values = np.sum(values,axis=0)
    #run cdist in a loop over coords to avoid overloading memory
    values = np.zeros((xyz.shape[0]))
    for i in range(coords.shape[0]):
        dist = spatial.distance.cdist(coords[None,i], xyz)
        dist *= dist
        values += 1./np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2) * np.exp(-dist[0]/(2*sigma**2))
    return values.reshape(n,n,n)

image = sumofgauss(coords,xyz,1.0)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(image[n/2]) #show a slice
plt.show()
```

M = 1000, N = 64 (~5 seconds):
[image: Sum of Gaussians in 3D Slice; N = 64]

M = 1000, N = 256 (~10 minutes):
[image: Sum of Gaussians in 3D Slice; N = 256]

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545745/numpy-generating-a-2d-sum-of-gaussians-pdf-as-an-array, which asks a similar question but in 2-d.  It assumes that the centers are at grid points, which might not be accurate enough for you.

Comment: Yes I did see that, thanks. However I do need it more accurate than at the grid points.

Comment: Looks like a job for `scipy.spatial.KDTree`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that many of your distance calculations will give zero weight after the exponential, you can probably drop a lot of your distances.  Doing big chunks of distance calculations while dropping distances which are greater than a threshhold is usually faster with `KDTree`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree # so we can get a `coo_matrix` output

def gaussgrid(coords, sigma = 1, n = 64, side = 100, eps = None):
    x_ = np.linspace(-side/2,side/2,n)
    x,y,z = np.meshgrid(x_,x_,x_,indexing='ij')
    xyz = np.column_stack((x.ravel(),y.ravel(),z.ravel()))
    if eps is None:
        eps = np.finfo('float64').eps
    thr = -np.log(eps) * 2 * sigma**2
    data_tree = cKDTree(coords)
    discr = 1000 # you can tweak this to get best results on your system
    values = np.empty(n**3)
    for i in range(n**3//discr + 1):
        slc = slice(i * discr, i * discr + discr)
        grid_tree = cKDTree(xyz[slc])
        dists = grid_tree.sparse_distance_matrix(data_tree, thr, output_type = 'coo_matrix')
        dists.data = 1./np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2) * np.exp(-dists.data/(2*sigma**2))
        values[slc] = dists.sum(1).squeeze()
    return values.reshape(n,n,n)
```

Now, even if you keep `eps = None` it'll be a bit faster  as you're still returning about 10% your distances, but with eps = 1e-6 or so, you should get a big speedup.  On my system:

```
%timeit out = sumofgauss(coords, xyz, 1.0)
1 loop, best of 3: 23.7 s per loop

%timeit out = gaussgrid(coords)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.12 s per loop

%timeit out = gaussgrid(coords, eps = 1e-6)
1 loop, best of 3: 382 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is significantly faster than my approach and appears to give similar results, though not exactly the same (I'll have to test for the best eps value). Can you explain what discr is for?

Comment: `discr` is basically how big a block of gridpoints you want to calculate at once.  If you do it all at once you will probably get a `MemoryError`

Comment: Got it. I'll play with that to see how best to optimize it. Thanks!